# Chain fell out of rear derailleur when wheel off.

Tags: chain, derailleur

I took my rear wheel off to fix a flat and hung the bike up by its front wheel to store. when I returned to put the tire back on the chain had slipped totally out of the rear derailleur, caged jockey gear & all. Any body ever see this & can the chain be replaced without breaking.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Was there any friend who could have pranked you? That definitely seems not possible...

Comment: Can you add a picture? As noted, this shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2):

That can't happen on a standard design rear derailer unless one of the jockey wheels (or some screws) falls out.  Are both wheels there?  Are there any missing screws?

Otherwise you must have an oddball derailer.